# Debian 11 - How can i lower the load on my server?

Tags: debian, hard-disk, performance, cpu, io

I'm currently running a Debian 11 with a load average of 4.
I want to lower this load - But i don't really know where to start, like a first step on at least the analisis part...

It's a Docker Server, with MySQL,

Below a few commands and its outputs, to give some overview of the server.

**Processes:**

```
administrator@srv-docker:~$ top -b -n 1 | head -n 20
top - 12:56:41 up 12 days,  4:28,  1 user,  load average: 4,19, 4,16, 4,14
Tasks: 242 total,   1 running, 241 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  1,4 us,  2,1 sy,  0,0 ni, 81,6 id, 14,9 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,0 si,  0,0 st
MiB Mem :   7955,3 total,    131,5 free,   1877,4 used,   5946,4 buff/cache
MiB Swap:      0,0 total,      0,0 free,      0,0 used.   5733,5 avail Mem

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 775840 systemd+  20   0 4996956 973276  35944 S  11,8  11,9   1019:50 mysqld
1856787 adminis+  20   0   10480   3956   3372 R  11,8   0,0   0:00.03 top
      1 root      20   0  164224  10424   7656 S   5,9   0,1   0:11.93 systemd
1184306 472       20   0 1974008 119776  60416 S   5,9   1,5  10:40.71 grafana-server
      2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.67 kthreadd
      3 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 rcu_gp
      4 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 rcu_par_gp
      6 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H-events_highpri
      8 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 mm_percpu_wq
      9 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 rcu_tasks_rude_
     10 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 rcu_tasks_trace
     11 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   3:07.86 ksoftirqd/0
     12 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0,0   0,0  21:54.79 rcu_sched
```

**Memory:**

```
administrator@srv-docker:~$ free -mh
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7,8Gi       1,8Gi       125Mi        49Mi       5,8Gi       5,6Gi
Swap:             0B          0B          0B
```

**IO Stat:**

```
root@srv-docker:~# iostat -m
Linux 5.10.0-16-amd64 (srv-docker)      23/07/2022      _x86_64_        (8 CPU)

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0,92    0,00    1,12    9,31    0,00   88,65

Device             tps    MB_read/s    MB_wrtn/s    MB_dscd/s    MB_read    MB_wrtn    MB_dscd
dm-0              0,03         0,00         0,00         0,00        757         54       2965
dm-1              0,22         0,00         0,00         0,00        351       1863        758
dm-2              0,00         0,00         0,00         0,00          2          0          0
dm-3              0,00         0,00         0,00         0,00          3          4          0
dm-4              0,01         0,00         0,00         0,00         15        136       3578
dm-5            204,93         0,00         1,90         0,01       3929    2009381      12419
sda             155,93         0,00         1,82         0,02       5071    1919118      20230
sr0               0,00         0,00         0,00         0,00          0          0          0
```

**VM Stat:**

```
root@srv-docker:~# vmstat
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 1  0      0 140500 216556 5868484    0    0     1   233    5    3  1  1 89  9  0
```

**Perf top:**

[image: Perf top results.]

**MP Stat:**

```
root@srv-docker:~# mpstat -P ALL
Linux 5.10.0-16-amd64 (srv-docker)      23/07/2022      _x86_64_        (8 CPU)

15:04:53     CPU    %usr   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal  %guest  %gnice   %idle
15:04:53     all    0,92    0,00    0,67    9,31    0,00    0,46    0,00    0,00    0,00   88,65
15:04:53       0    1,14    0,00    0,80    7,02    0,00    1,05    0,00    0,00    0,00   90,00
15:04:53       1    0,67    0,00    0,64   27,24    0,00    0,46    0,00    0,00    0,00   70,99
15:04:53       2    1,13    0,00    0,86   12,72    0,00    0,50    0,00    0,00    0,00   84,79
15:04:53       3    0,70    0,00    0,47    3,16    0,00    0,29    0,00    0,00    0,00   95,38
15:04:53       4    1,11    0,00    0,84   10,40    0,00    0,41    0,00    0,00    0,00   87,24
15:04:53       5    0,74    0,00    0,46    2,82    0,00    0,27    0,00    0,00    0,00   95,71
15:04:53       6    1,14    0,00    0,82    8,55    0,00    0,39    0,00    0,00    0,00   89,10
15:04:53       7    0,71    0,00    0,45    2,66    0,00    0,28    0,00    0,00    0,00   95,90
```

Please, can someone help me?
Thanks in advance... Any light is appreciate it.

Comment: Is there any practical reason you want to lower the load? You could start by uninstalling software, transforming your functional server to a paperweight, but I suppose you depend on the software that is running on it. Grafana would be a good starting point for that

Comment: Shouldn't you obviously start optimizing the performances your mysql server ? (databases / engines / caches…) To that respect, you might find more useful info on the dba SE site.

Comment: Currently the front-end of my apps are running slowly. I want to optimize the server so things will get a little better.

Comment: @MC68020 Yes, of course. But i supose that there is stuff i can do on Debian itself, alongside the MySQL tweaks. Any tips?

Comment: Maybe you could start form there : https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/high-performance-mysql/9781492080503/ch04.html

Comment: I see that on column "-----io----" when using "vmstat" command the BO value is 233... I don't think this is normal. I'll take a read at your docs and see if i can come up with something... If you have any other tips, let me know.

Comment: You appear to be using the 1st statistics printed out by these tools, and that's not a good idea with most of them (vmstat, iostat, mpstat, and maybe top).  The 1st stats are a summary of the activity since last boot, and that's usually different from what's happening now.  I suggest having the tools generate 3 or 4 sets of output with a 3-5 second delay between, and look at the last set.  Ideally, you'll log 10 minutes' worth and scan the log for trends and patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
%Cpu(s):  1,4 us,  2,1 sy,  0,0 ni, 81,6 id, 14,9 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,0 si,  0,0 st
```

Note that the `%Cpu(s)` row says your system is 81.6% *idle*.

How many CPU cores do you have?

If the number of CPU cores is higher than the integer part of the load average value, you have nothing to worry about: your system is not even working that hard. (If you were thinking that load >1 is a cause for concern, that is old advice that was applicable for single-core single-CPU systems only.)

Press <kbd>1</kbd> in `top` to see the per-core classification of CPU usage (or per-hyperthread, if your CPU has that feature and it's enabled). The number of `%CpuN` lines you'll see will reflect the number of CPU cores/hyperthreads available on your system.

Your RAM is mostly used as caches and there is even some of it totally free, so clearly you have plenty of RAM for your workload.

The `mpstat` indicates the `%iowait` tends to dominate the CPU usage categories: if this pattern continues when you gather a larger set of data over some timespan, then this system might benefit most from faster storage, if you absolutely want to upgrade something.

The dominant item in `perf top` output is `__softirqentry_text_start` which is related to interrupt processing; in a server system, that would usually be related to either storage or network activity.

The `iostat -m` indicates your disk I/O workload has clearly been mostly-writes, so your system probably has everything it routinely needs in RAM and the write operations are essentially just write cache flushes. But I would recommend following @Sotto Voce's advice in the comments, and letting the `vmstat`/`iostat`/`mpstat` tools generate multiple sets of output over time, e.g. with `iostat -m 5 5`.